# Sub a number with column numbers and show the results in a row

Tags: excel

I have a number in cell B2 and I want to make a sub this number with each number in the column C.
The results will be presented in a row (and I want to use the cross in the right corner of the cell to autofill).
Let me explain you what I want to show in each cell:

E2: $B$2-C5

F2: $B$2-C6

G2: $B$2-C7

In order not to write it manually in each cell, how can I change it (autocomplete C5, C6, C7) with the usage of the cross?
I tried to use the dollar like $B$2-$C5 and then drag the cross but it fills all the cells with the C5 value and not C6, C7 etc

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **E2** enter:

```
=$B$2-INDEX($C:$C,COLUMNS($A:E))
```

and copy across:

[image]

Comment: Is this solution also working if the column C is in another sheet?

Comment: @dali1985  You would replace ***$C:$C*** with the correct external reference.